# Angular bracket arguments don't get replaced in Cucumber Feature file after completion of execution in cucumber js

Tags: node.js, cucumber, cucumberjs

I'm using cucumber js with node js and webdriverio.

I have written hooks in step definition file like..

```
Given(/^I login with username (.*) and password (.*)$/, function(username,password) {
       pageModule.open();
       pageModule.Login("abc","abc");
       return Promise.resolve();
});
```

I have used Feature file as follows

```
Scenario: Create New
          Given I login with username "<username>" and password "<password>"
```

After execution , reports are generated like..   and  in feature file is not replaced with actual values

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the full Scenario as off of the data you provided you have not passed in an actual username or password from a table which is needed when using <>

Comment: I'm not fetching data from datatable, rather excel so I guess its fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to take multiple user names and passwords:

1) We need to declare it as Scenario Outline instead only Scenario
2) We need to create a Scenario Outline in below format:

```
Scenario Outline: Create New
Given I login with username <username> and password <password>
Examples:
|username|password|
|firstUserName|firstPassword|
|secondUserName|secondPassword|
```

By this way, our scenario will be repeated with multiple examples what we are proving in Examples table shown like above.